# How to play a clean run on undertale for switch

Tags: undertale

I am aware this question has been asked, but the answers are for steam/pc, and I play on switch. The endings I have achieved, in order, are neutral, pacifist, genocide.
I would like to play pacifist again, but I would rather avoid the repercussions.

Answer (score 1):

Go into the game settings (open settings and the game data menu - undertale) and reset the data. Resetting the data will reset your run logs, which would let you run another, "clean" run.

Comment: Does this actually work? I thought that the flag set by clearing the genocide route is the one thing that cannot be removed, even with a "true reset"

Comment: True resets dont reset the game data, which means the flag telling the game "hey, they did genocide" is still there. If you reset the game DATA, it wipes the flag.

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify these details in your answer? I believe you, but I find at times it is difficult to distingiush between a reset in Undertale, true reset in Undertale, and resetting the game's data through the Switch menu.